# My sister’s cousin’s

Tags: translation

Google doesn’t understand this sentence, which came up in conversation:

The black hat is my sister’s cousin’s.

How would you translate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Il cappello nero è del cugino (o della cugina) di mia sorella

However, let me add that since "my sister's cousin" is most definitely also "my cousin", the speaker is formulating the sentence in an unnecessarily complicated form, as it could be expressed simply as:

> the black hat is my cousin's.